# Field `referent` treated specially by GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was looking at `java.lang.ref.Reference` and have found an interesting(at least for me) line in JDK 1.8_131:

`private T referent;         /* Treated specially by GC */`

What does it mean?

How does GC treat it specially?

Is it a truth that any variable with this name will be treated in the same way?

I've searched for `referent` in the Java specification but have found nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comment is only stating, what can be derived from the [documentation of the package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/package-summary.html) and the individual classes. The special treatment only applies to the field of `java.lang.ref.Reference .referent`, within this specific JRE, as an implementation detail. Generally, if you want to understand the semantics, you should look at the documentation first, before (if ever) looking into the source code.

Since this is an implementation detail, you won’t find it in the specifications. The specification only tells you the semantic of [`SoftReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html), [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), and [`PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html). For a Java application developer, the existence of this field is irrelevant, as they will only use it indirectly by creating instances of these three classes, whose documentation specifies the semantic.

For the JVM implementation, it isn’t sufficient to know the special `referent` field, as it is inherited by all these reference classes, the actual treatment depends on the actual type of the reference instance the garbage collector is looking at. This behavior has been hardcoded into the JVM, to work with this specific implementation of the class library.

Answer (score 4):

Well yes, Holger is right; but if you are like me - I sort of like this details, just like you. So I like to look in the source code and do a little `grep` in the hotspot sources. And I found a test called: `ReferenceGetLoopTest` that has:

```
 if (field.getName().equals("referent") 
       && field.getDeclaringClass().equals(getMetaAccess().lookupJavaType(Reference.class)))
```

That is the first indication that indeed this field is treated in a different way. But that was in graalvm, so here is yet another indication that this field is different in: `hotspot/src/cpu/x86/vm/templateInterpreterGenerator_x86.cpp`:

```
   const int referent_offset = java_lang_ref_Reference::referent_offset;
   guarantee(referent_offset > 0, "referent offset not initialized");
```

There are many other places too... So, yes, your conclusion is right

Comment: cool, my grep didn't found this. btw, looks like this tests just looks that field is presented, so this isn't a GC behaviour /shrug

Comment: @OlegKovalov forgot to mention... there are many other references in the source code that mention `G1` with that